# Should my thread be moved?

Tags: discussion, questions

I opened [this](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/81278/how-to-handle-lending-tools-equipment-to-freelancing-acquaintance) question today, and someone mentioned it would better fit at [Freelancing SE](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com). I posted my post in workplace because I'd never been on freelancing and I didn't know it existed.

Should my question be moved? If yes, how can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

I moved it because the primary focus of your question is asking about the specifics of the freelancing arrangement.

To migrate, generally you need a moderator to do that if the site is not prepopulated in the migration target list (which freelancing is not).

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like someone already migrated it.